# How to get URL parameter from force.com site in LWC?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, force.com-sites

I have created an LWC that takes the recordId from the URL.

https://myurl.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/invoice?c__recordId=a0B1q00000Jy2ZeEAJ

Now I have added the LWC in the aura component and added the aura component in a Visualforce page. Then I made the Visualforce page public by creating a new Force.com Site.

My new URL is https://myurl.force.com/invoice

I have tried
https://myurl.force.com/invoice?id=a0B1q00000Jy2ZeEAJ

I get the parameter from the URL to my LWC. I use wire to get the record data but it is throwing this error:

> You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.

How to solve this problem?

**PublicInvoice.app**

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess" access="Global">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:molliePayment"/> 
</aura:application>
```

**PublicPayment.page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Verkoopfactuur__c" lightningStylesheets="true">
<apex:includeLightning />    
<div id="LightningAppDivId"></div>

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:PublicInvoice", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:molliePayment", {
            recordId : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
        },
        "LightningAppDivId",
        function(component) {
            
        });
    });
</script>

</apex:page>
```

molliePayment.js

```
@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$recordId',
    fields: VERKOOPFACTUUR_FIELDS,
    optionalFields: ACCOUNT_MERK_FIELDS
})// verkoopfactuur;    
wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        let message = 'Unknown error';
        if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
            message = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
        } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
            message = error.body.message;
        }
        console.log(message);
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error loading contact',
                message,
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );
    } else if (data) {
        console.log('Reading data: ', data);
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        this.verkoopfactuur = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You used `{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}` in your LightningOut setup. Try setting the query parameter with the name `id`, rather than `Id`, or change to ensure the name matches case.

Comment: Using {!$CurrentPage.parameters.id} solved my problem.